# south. migrate entire database

Tags: django, django-south

how can i migrate entiry db at one step? south`s startmigration command can work only with single application

Answer (score 4):

If you want to **create** a migration, `manage.py startmigration` is deprecated (see `manage.py help startmigration`), you should be using `manage.py schemamigration` (as described in [the docs](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html#the-first-migration/)), and you should definitely be doing this individually on each app.

If you want to **run** migrations (in other words do the actual altering of the database, which I'm guessing is the case), The command for that is `manage.py migrate` which, if run without any arguments, will migrate *all of your apps* to the latest migration available.

My deployment script just has `manage.py migrate`, and it works fine without manual intervention, no matter how many apps have new migrations that need to be run.

Comment: Internally, this isn't one single step as behind the scenes, multiple migrations are being run and multiple SQL statements are being executed. However, it's only one command that only needs to be typed once, so from the perspective of the person that's performing it it's a single step.

Answer (score 3):

Even with raw SQL, you wont be able to migrate an entire database in a *single step* as you need a query per table. You can however, create migrations for all apps, and then run them all at once. That's the closest thing you'll come to a one step migration.

Comment: that`s the problem. how automate this process if I don`t know how many applications will be at the end?

Comment: The applications should be reflected in the database and vice versa. So if you know your database, you should know your applications.